# access to map<int,pair<double,double>> elements

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have passed a `map<double, pair<int, int>>` through a function and now I want to have access to the elements in the pair, how is it possible? My problem looks like below:

```
void func(map<double ,pair<int ,int > & f)
{

  int d= b+c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sure `a` exists:

```
void func(int a,map<int,pair<double,double>>& m)
{
    double d = m[a].first + m[a].second;
}
```

otherwise:

```
void func(int a,map<int,pair<double,double>>& m)
{
    double d = 0;
    if( m.find(a) != m.end() ) 
        d = m[a].first + m[a].second;
}
```

Comment: unless you want to add data by accident you might want to use find rather than accessing directly.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help (in C++11): (https://ideone.com/WcFHaw)

```
void print(const std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>> &m)
{
    for (const auto& p : m)
    {
        std::cout << "key = " << p.first << ", value = {" << p.second.first << ", " << p.second.second << "}"<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
void func(map<int, pair<double, double> >& m)
{
    for (auto i : m)
    {
        double d = i.second.first + i.second.second;
    }
}
```

Also it will be useful to read manual about maps, pairs and templates.